# ListBox only displaying first item selected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I am working on a `ASPX/VB` site. I have a `ListBox` but when you select multiple options, only 1 item gets passed to the next page where it puts the item into an un-ordered list.

I can't seem to get multiple selected items to appear.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" id="dlcenter1" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
    <asp:ListItem name="option0[]" Value="0" multiple="multiple">None</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem name="option1[]" Value="1" multiple="multiple">Assistant managers</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem name="option2[]" Value="2" multiple="multiple">Customer service representatives</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem name="option3[]" Value="3" multiple="multiple">General managers</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem name="option4[]" Value="4" multiple="multiple">Hitch installers</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem name="option5[]" Value="5" multiple="multiple">Manager trainee</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem name="option6[]" Value="6" multiple="multiple">MOONLIGHTERS WANTED</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem name="option7[]" Value="7" multiple="multiple">Store managers</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem name="option8[]" id="option8" Value="8" multiple="multiple">U-Box Customer Care Rep</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:ListBox>
```

**VB**

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        dlCenter1.DataBind()
        'dlCenter2.DataBind()
        'dlCenter3.DataBind()
        'dlCenter4.DataBind()
        'dlCenter5.DataBind()
        GetEntityInfo()
    End If
End Sub


Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

    Session.Clear()
    lblError.Visible = False

    'Declare variables to place into session
    Dim dl1 As String = dlcenter1.SelectedItem.Text
    'Dim dl2 As String = dlCenter2.SelectedItem.Text
    'Dim dl3 As String = dlCenter3.SelectedItem.Text
    'Dim dl4 As String = dlCenter4.SelectedItem.Text
    'Dim dl5 As String = dlCenter5.SelectedItem.Text

    Dim name As String = txtName.Text.ToString.Trim()
    Dim address As String = txtAddress.Text.ToString.Trim()
    Dim city As String = txtCity.Text.ToString.Trim()
    Dim state As String = ddlState.SelectedItem.Value.ToString.Trim()
    Dim zipcode As String = txtZipCode.Text.ToString.Trim()
    Dim phone As String = txtPhone.Text.ToString.Trim()
    Dim fax As String = txtFax.Text.ToString.Trim()

    'Session validation
    If Not dlCenter1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        Session.Add("dl1", dl1.ToString)
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim selectedItems As String = String.Empty

    For Each item As ListItem In dlCenter1.Items
        If item.Selected Then
            selectedItems += "<li>" & item.Value & "</li>"
        End If
    Next

    Session.Add("dl1", selectedItems)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to know that the ListItem is a collection and you need to go through the items one by one otherwise you cannot assign the whole collection into one single variable.

so to do this you need to make a loop in your function and here is the answer in C#, hope you could convert it to VB.

> ```
>         string selectedItems = string.Empty;
>
>         foreach (ListItem item in dlcenter1.Items)
>         {
>             if (item.Selected)
>             {
>                 //I used ',' to separate the selected values you can separate it with other characters or even use a list to save the selected items 
>                 selectedItems += item.value + ", ";
>             }
>         }
>
>         Session.Add("dl1", selectedItems);
> ```